# Try to add more property to Jquery for .css()

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform, translate

I have this line of code that helps me to add a parallax effect to an arrow. but i want to rotate it in the same time and I tried to add another property of "transform" but it does not work, maybe something is typed wrong. Can someone help me?

So, the line that works is this:

```
$("#arroww").css("transform",'translate(0px, -'+Scroleaza/3+'%)');
```

And I tried to use this but still, only the parallax effect is working. If I put the rotate property first, it works and the parallax effect stops working and vice-versa.

```
$("#dirty").css( "transform",'translate(0px, -'+Scroleaza/3+'%)',"transform",'rotate(50deg)');
```

Comment: Read the duplicate or the docs: https://api.jquery.com/css

Answer (score 1):

Better to just use .addClass() even if you have 1 or more. More maintainable and readable.

If you really have the urge to do multiple CSS properties then use the following:

```
$("#dirty").css({
   'property' : 'value',
   'property' : 'value',
   'property' : 'value'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass multiple properties as an ***object***.

```
$("#dirty").css({ 
  "transform": 'translate(0px, -' + Scroleaza / 3 + '%)',
  "transform": 'rotate(50deg)' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple `.css()` (or basically any JQuery function) calls together:

```
$("#dirty")
  .css("transform", 'translate(0px, -' + Scroleaza / 3 + '%)')
  .css("transform", 'rotate(50deg)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object containing multiple CSS properties.

```
$("#dirty").css({
  "transform":
  'translate(0px, -' + Scroleaza / 3 + '%)',
  "transform":
  'rotate(50deg)'
});
```

EDIT:
Syntax errors...

Comment: All that's going to do is give you a syntax error